# What is the difference in minifying these two pieces of code?

Tags: angularjs, minify

i have the following non minfied and minified version code for controller:

**non-minified version code :**

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
   //code for controller
});
```

**minified version code :**

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
    //code for controller
}]);
```

i don't know why minified version code is preffered ? what is the difference between minified and non-minified version code ?

Comment: Are you asking why do we minify code in general or what's the difference between the two, the "minified" version in your example isn't minified in the sense of the term.

Comment: You minify to reduce download size and obscure intent. You have to use the array version of AngularJS code in order for minification to not break AngularJS.

Comment: I think it's because minifying mangles the names of variables, and without explicitly mapping the names, like in the second example, it could break the injection.

Comment: We use minification on our production Angular app.  One of the controllers goes from around 14kb down to 6kb.  We also gzip content on the server, so it's closer to 1.8kb actual download size to the user.  To use a minifier, we have to follow the 'minified' convention you showed above.

Comment: I propose that the content of the question has merit, even if the original question was rough and indirect.  Edits made maybe worth upvoting now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minification renames variables (among other things). Your first sample will no longer work when minified, as angular won't know what to inject when `$scope` and `$http` are renamed. Your second example, using the array syntax, tells angular what to inject regardless of the variable names.

(There are syntax errors in both of your examples: `PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http)` should be `function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http)`.)

Note: when using named functions as you are, there's another option for minification-safe angular code:

```
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', PhoneListCtrl);

PhoneListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

function PhoneListCtrl($scope, $http) {
  //code for controller
}
```

Finally, if you really prefer your first example, you can use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) to pre-process your angular code and make it minification-safe.